# I'm trying to make leave/disconnect VC command for discord bot (js), I'm facing some issues discussed bellow

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

The code won't work perfectly, i find couple of issues:

1. When I'm connected to a `VC` and trying to attempt the command the `bot leaves the VC` but `triggers two functions` at a time i.e., *General leave funtion* and *author not in the same channel.*
2. When i give command `being outside the VC`(bot connected to the VC) the bot responds with function *we are not in a same channel funtion.*, rather i want `it to respond` with *you're not connected to  VC*
3. When i give command while `being outside VC` and `bot not connected to VC`, it responds nothing and `at console` i get error:

`(node:37) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: cannot read property "id" of undefined`

Code:

```js
client.on('message', async (message) => {
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  if (command === 'leave') {
    let authorVoice = message.member.voice;

   
    const embed1 = new discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle('`You are not in a Voice Channel!`')
      .setColor('RED')
      .setTimestamp();
    if (!authorVoice.channel) return message.channel.send(embed1);

    const embed2 = new discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle('⛔`We are not in a same Voice Channel`')
      .setColor('YELLOW')
      .setTimestamp();
    if (authorVoice.channel.id !== client.voice.channel.id)
      return message.channel.send(embed2);
   const embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle('`Successfully left the Voice Channel`✔')
      .setColor('RED')
      .setTimestamp();
    authorVoice.channel.leave()
    message.channel.send(embed);
  }
});
```

Can someone help me fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`client.voice` doesn't have a `channel` property. It means that `client.voice.channel` is undefined. When you try to read the `id` of it, you receive the error that you *"cannot read property "id" of undefined"*.

You probably want the [`connections`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientVoiceManager?scrollTo=connections) that is a collection of [`VoiceConnection`s](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceConnection). A connection does have a `channel` property but as `client.voice.connections` is a collection, you need to find the one you need first.

As you only want to check if a channel with the same ID exists, you can use the [`.some()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=some) method. In its callback function you check if any of the connections has the same channel ID as the message author's channel ID. So, instead of `if(authorVoice.channel.id !== client.voice.channel.id)` you could create a variable that returns a boolean. It returns `true` if the bot is in the same channel and `false` otherwise:

```js
const botIsInSameChannel = client.voice.connections.some(
  (c) => c.channel.id === authorVoice.channel.id,
);

// bot is not in the same channel
if (!botIsInSameChannel)
  return message.channel.send(embed2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated code if anyone watching for:

```js
client.on('message', async message => {
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    if (command === 'leave') {
             let authorVoice = message.member.voice; 
        const botIsInSameChannel = client.voice.connections.some(
  (c) => c.channel.id === authorVoice.channel.id,
); 
     const embed1 = new discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(':no_entry_sign: You are not in a Voice Channel!')
      .setColor('RED')
      .setTimestamp();
        if(!authorVoice.channel) return message.channel.send(embed1);
        
    const embed2 = new discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(':no_entry: We are not in a same Voice Channel')
      .setColor('YELLOW')
      .setTimestamp();
        if (!botIsInSameChannel) return message.channel.send(embed2)      
        
        const embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle('Successfully left the Voice Channel✔')
      .setColor('RED')
      .setTimestamp();
        authorVoice.channel.leave();
        message.channel.send(embed);
      }
    });
```